# RocketChat: copy messages on private channel as they are pinned (or starred)

Tags: chatbot, rocket.chat

I've to write a daemon (or script) running inside my RocketChat server that **automatically clone messages** from any direct chat to a private channel **as soon as they went pinned or starred by the user** (I don't want to integrate any additional button or option on phone apps neither on the web app).

I am a newbie in rocketchat and I've read a lot of info (eg. how mongodb works etc.), but I cannot understand **if a bot is the right choice for this task**.

I've installed the chat application on a Ubuntu Server via snap.